# Any way to convert an XLF to a SWF with scripts?

Tags: excel, flash, automation, business-objects, xcelsius

I found out that an XLF file is just a ZIP folder that contains an XML doc and an 'xldoc' which is the Excel model that the template uses.

http://myxcelsius.com/2010/04/25/xcelsius-xlf-dissected/

I can figure out how to automate replacing the xldoc with our updated model, but is there any way to create the SWF file from the XLF through a script or possibly an SDK that would allow this?

We usually use XCelsius to import the new model Excel file, then export the XLF as a SWF, but we have 25 or so of these to do every month, so automating this process would help us out a lot.

Comment: _" is there any way to create the SWF file from the XLF"_ SWF is a compiled **application**. Asking this is like asking how to convert a PDF into APK (Android Application) or how to convert one MP3 file into a iOS app (for AppStore etc)... Hopefully someone can help you anyways. Maybe you want to keep all bytes that define SWF app as it is and then replace only the bytes that represent the XML/XLF data? Sounds like you need a developer to make a custom tool?